# Adding Shade Over Span Or Div Using CSS or CSS3

Tags: css

[image]

I know i can overlay a transparent image on a div to achieve this, but the question is, is this possible only using css3?
It is actually a progress bar with yellow color has a slight light shade or gradient on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create progress bar like that with bootstrap

**DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/190/**

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
    <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.progress-bar {
    background: rgba(237,220,109,1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(237,220,109,1) 0%, rgba(237,220,109,1) 31%, rgba(255,245,180,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(237,220,109,1)), color-stop(31%, rgba(237,220,109,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,245,180,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(237,220,109,1) 0%, rgba(237,220,109,1) 31%, rgba(255,245,180,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(237,220,109,1) 0%, rgba(237,220,109,1) 31%, rgba(255,245,180,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(237,220,109,1) 0%, rgba(237,220,109,1) 31%, rgba(255,245,180,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(237,220,109,1) 0%, rgba(237,220,109,1) 31%, rgba(255,245,180,1) 100%);
}

.progress {
    background: #808080;
}
```

Comment: Your Comment is the answer. Please replace the demo url with correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Oh got it, i used following code.

```
.bar :after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient( -45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent );
    z-index: 1;
    background-size: 220% 102px;
    animation: move 2s linear infinite;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```